# рендерить React - компоненты в заранее заготовленные div?

Tags: reactjs

Насколько будет  правильным (допустимым) подход для отображения каких либо 
данных рендерить React - компоненты  в заранее заготовленные div , для вывода следующей порции данных перерендерить их в те же самые div с другими значениями в С2 ( как альтернатива изменению state ) . как то примерно так -

```
       class C2 extends React.Component 
       {
        render() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.ak}</div>;
       }
       }

      for (var i=4 ; i<7 ; i++) {
      var tt="s"+i ;
      var sc=document.getElementById(tt) ;
      ReactDOM.render(<C2 ak={objRecords[i].ak} />  , sc) ;
      }
```

Comment: _как альтернатива изменению state_ а зачем тогда вообще реакт?))

Comment: Считаете приведенный пример недопустимым ?

Comment: Почему недопустимым? Просто бесполезным. Собственна вся польза реакта в реакции на изменения стейта, а перерендер перечеркивает все преимущества и ничем не отличается от нативного javascript. Рендер в заранее заготовленные блоки имеет смысл, при начальной инициализации страницы, например блок меню, блок профиля юзера, само приложение, а потом менять стейт при изменении данных. В вашем же примере просто усложните себе работу и увеличите время выполнения